# Cocos2d No Autorotation on specific CCScene

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a Menu Scene that I would like to be Portrait Only, then I have a `gamescene` that I would like to only allow `landscape-home-button-right` but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I tried adding `shouldAutoRotate..` to the CCScene but that seems to only work on the RootViewController. How can I stop autorotation within the CCScene? Thank you for any help!

I'm using Cocos2D 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose you to do next steps:
1. Create a singleton that manage your orientation depending on what scene is running.
2. When you enter a new scene you should say to this singleton what orientation this scene support
3. To your app delegate add something like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return [[YourSingleton manager] supportingInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window {
    return [[YourSingleton manager] supportingInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

I did not test this before but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that actually makes a lot of sense and is pretty elegant. Thank you, I will implement this later!